# Is there a difference without curly braces when using hash as an argument?

Tags: ruby, hash, literals

It seems there is no difference between these two expressions.

```
h = {a: 1, b: 2}
h.merge({c: 3, d: 4})
h.merge(c: 3, d: 4)
```

Is there a problematic case if I omit the curly braces when using `Hash` as an argument?

Comment: Not at all, even more: Rubocop/Ruby style guidelines _suggest_ to omit curlies around hash in such a case.

Comment: To omit the braces the hash pairs must be the last of the arguments. For example, `def hi(a,b); puts "a=#{a}, b=#{b}"; end; hi(3,:a=>1, :b=>2) #=> a=3, b={:a=>1, :b=>2}; hi(:a=>1, 2) #=> SyntaxError: (irb):873: syntax error, unexpected..`.

Comment: It's well-explained in [Flanagan and Matsumoto's book](https://books.google.ca/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=ruby+argument+hash+omit+braces&source=bl&ots=fJFmwe7zgC&sig=m0A-lKxFrSD6_ryrwPwdQ1hfwOU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1wem2rZfLAhUKcj4KHdIcBdAQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=ruby%20argument%20hash%20omit%20braces&f=false). One thing I hadn't thought about is that when you omit parentheses around arguments, the hash's curly braces *must* be omitted, lest Ruby treat the hash as a block.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no difference between both versions.

Furthermore, it is a common Ruby/Rails idiom to omit the curly brackets when the hash is the last argument to a method. Compare the following common examples:

```
validates :foo, { presence: true }
validates :foo, presence: true

link_to "Foos", foo_path, { class: "foo" }
link_to "Foos", foo_path, class: "foo"
```

Comment: Hey there @spickermann, great explanation, but why is it that it's commonly omitted only when the hash is the last argument?

Comment: @LordAlpaca Definitely not an expert in Ruby conventions, but I'd assume that omitting curly braces when a hash is not the last argument could be misread as individual arguments to the function being called.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 "ways" or syntax of declaring hashes, the old and the new;

The old way is very rigid in that it follows the following formula:
Parenthesis `(` curly bracket `{`, space , key object (usually a *:symbol*, but can be anything else) `:one`, space, hash rocket, and space `=>`, value object `1`, closures. The whole thing would look like this:

```
hash_object = ({ :one => 1, :two => 2 })
```

Skipping the spaces will work, but it's not proper syntax.

The new syntax was built to be amenable to folk who used JSON a lot, so instead of using EXPLICIT symbols (i.e. `:one` in the previous example) the new syntax forces the keys to be of symbol class, and follows a much simpler formula: 
Parenthesis `(`, name of the key `one`, colon `:`, (optional space ), value `1`, and closures. Under the new syntax, the hash creation would look like this:

```
hash_object = (one: 1, two: 2)
```

As you can see, the new syntax is simpler than the old, but it is less flexible as it forces symbols to be the keys, and less intuitive.

Lastly, there are other useful "idioms" or shortcuts around hashes; for instance, if you use a hash as an argument to a method/function, **and it is the last argument**, then you can just use the new syntax without parenthesis and Ruby will interpret the chain of key/value pairs as one unique argument:

```
method arg1, arg2, a: 1, b: 2, c:3
```

is the same as

```
method(arg1, arg2, ({ :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3 }))
```

My recommendation is **stick with the old, rigid form!**. Ruby was built to be intuitive and easy to read for developers, not to be "elegant" or short. Using the old syntax will force you to think about what you're doing, and it will be very easy to debug as you know exactly what Ruby is "thinking" when you provide the hash. One last word of caution: use the parenthesis too! Don't skip them, or sometimes Ruby might mistake your hash for a code block.